# Editable Grid in AngularJS using ngGrid Plugin

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm working on ngGrid, trying to implement editable grid. In this editable grid, I want to handle validations for the data provided as input while editing.

I also want to implement a functionality where if the data in the cell is left empty then the user should not be able to tab to the next cell.

Please let me know if anyone have any idea about this.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you did (your code). And what exactly is your problem? Tell us what you did to find a solution yourself.

Comment: Hi smartmeta, I just created a simple ngGrid in AngularJS, used cell template to do validations on that particular cell. This was with respect to the input validations but I want not able to stop the navigation by shifting it to adjacent cell as e.StopPropogation for tab key does't work in that.